# Headphone not working Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS - ASUS K55VM

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on ASUS K55VM. When I finished to install Ubuntu and some basic package and software, my headphone was not working.

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=9c6ddb7befa3104826bbc6572b6ef98a26ef65fa

Comment: What kind of headphones do you have and how are they connected to your computer? In case of USB, please provide the output of `lsusb` with them plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with ubuntu 12.04 I solved it by turning of my computer removing the battery and hold the power button for 5-6 seconds to remove any charge from the capacitors and it seemed to work for me. Maybe it's not that but it's worth a shot.